# ConnectionResetError('Connection lost') python asyncio server

Tags: python-asyncio, python-3.7, redis-py

I am writing a redis server for a redis client connecting on port 9000 (using redis-py).

I wrote a simple test code for now to check if the server is receiving the client's command. My code is as follows:

**client.py**

```
import redis

r = redis.Redis(
    host="127.0.0.1",
    port=9000
)

v = r.set('foo', 1)
print(v)

v = r.set('bar', '1')
```

**server.py**

```
import asyncio

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 15000


async def exo_redis(reader, writer):

    try:
        while True:
            data = await reader.readuntil(b'\r\n')
            # data = await reader.read(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            print("Data: ", data)
            response = "+OK\r\n"
            writer.write(response.encode())
            await writer.drain()

        writer.close()

    except asyncio.streams.IncompleteReadError:
        pass


def start_server():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    coro = asyncio.start_server(exo_redis, HOST, PORT)
    server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
    print("Serving on ", HOST, "port: ", PORT)
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nShutting Down Server...\n")
    finally:
        server.close()
        loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
        loop.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_server()
```

Upon running this, I am getting the output with the following exception:

```
Data:  b'*3\r\n'
Data:  b'$3\r\n'
Data:  b'SET\r\n'
Data:  b'$3\r\n'
Data:  b'foo\r\n'
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<exo_redis() done, defined at app.py:13> exception=ConnectionResetError('Connection lost')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 23, in exo_redis
    await writer.drain()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/streams.py", line 348, in drain
    await self._protocol._drain_helper()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/streams.py", line 202, in _drain_helper
    raise ConnectionResetError('Connection lost')
ConnectionResetError: Connection lost
Data:  b'*3\r\n'
Data:  b'$3\r\n'
Data:  b'SET\r\n'
Data:  b'$3\r\n'
Data:  b'bar\r\n'
Data:  b'$1\r\n'
Data:  b'1\r\n'
```

For some reason, the 1st command sent from the client throws an exception but the second one does not.

If I use reader.read(1024) (commented in the code), I get the following output:

```
Data:  b'*3\r\n$3\r\nSET\r\n$3\r\nfoo\r\n$1\r\n1\r\n'
Data:  b'*3\r\n$3\r\nSET\r\n$3\r\nbar\r\n$1\r\n1\r\n'
```

This works sometimes and there is no exception thrown, but some other times I am getting this exception with the command not being read completely. Any ideas on how this can be rectified and I can ensure that the entire command is being received at the server end?